# variable in Jquery For Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ajax success function like below

```
success: function(result) {

    for (var i = 0; i < result['Result'].length; i++) {

        if (result['Result'][i]['ClusterId'] == '2414040001') {
            if (result['Result'][i]['UserLatitude'] != '' &&
                result['Result'][i]['UserLatitude'] != null) {
                window.UserLatitude = result['Result'][i][
                    'UserLatitude'
                ];
            } else {
                window.UserLatitude = '';
            }

            if (result['Result'][i]['UserLongitude'] != '' &&
                result['Result'][i]['UserLongitude'] != null) {
                window.UserLongitude = result['Result'][i][
                    'UserLongitude'
                ];
            } else {
                window.UserLongitude = '';
            }

            console.log("LAT:" + UserLatitude + "LONG:" +
                UserLongitude);
        }


    }


    const myLatLng = {
        lat: UserLatitude,
        lng: UserLongitude
    };
    console.log(myLatLng);
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(
        "googleMap"), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng,
    });

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: -33.890,
            lng: 151.274
        },
        map,
        title: "Hello World!",
    });




}
```

I am getting latitude and longitude from remote server and want use it for Google Map.
Its working fine if I use const like below

const myLatLng = { lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274 };

but if I use variable for it, its giving me error like below

```
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lat: not a number
```

I am not getting idea what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: please don't set anything off `window`

Comment: use parseFloat on variables.

Comment: @naxsi, parseFloat  have solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response returned by the server might be string.Can you please try this code to parse the lat and long value to float lat and lng value using `parseFloat()` method from javascript.

```js
// const myLatLng = { lat: UserLatitude, lng: UserLongitude };
// change above code to 
const myLatLng = { lat: parseFloat(UserLatitude), lng: parseFloat(UserLongitude) };
                  console.log(myLatLng);
                  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: myLatLng,
                  });
                
                  new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
                    map,
                    title: "Hello World!",
                  });
```